# Why is the Triage review queue not mentioned in the Help Center?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

The ["access review queues" privilege in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) says that upon hitting 500 reputation, you get access to the First Posts and Late Answers review queues.

But it doesn't say anything about the Triage review queue, which you also gain access to at 500 reputation. Why doesn't it mention Triage?

Comment: Maybe because it's specific to the Stack Overflow site? I don't know but that's my guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The privilege pages are centralized across the network of sites.

I hit a similar issue then I researched [the create tags privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260441/158100) over on MSE.

In the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5189164#5189164) [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) explained that the privilege help text pages *can be* localized per site but then it has to be a translation. The effort that is needed upfront is not small and after that you added another maintenance burden.

So it is a bit of an inconvenience to not have an accurate text there that matches the available functionalities. However, I don't think fixing it should be a priority for the next 6 to 8 weeks.